# Text-to-speech SAPI5 AccessViolationException when using another voice

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, text-to-speech, sapi

I've installed czech voice for SAPI5 Eliska22k. It works fine on Windows 7. Now I've windows 8 and on calling `Speak` method it gives me `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Also I tried use `SpeechSynthesizer` from .NET System.Speech. It can also see voice Eliska22k installed (on W7 it works only with SAPI5) but it will not write any exception it just wont start. On `SelectVoice("Eliska22k")` method program just exit.

Default voices works fine as in SAPI5 also in default Speech.

I've installed `SpeechPad` and it works with voice Eliska22k fine. I cannot found there problem is.

```
SpeechSynthesizer voice = new SpeechSynthesizer();

voice.SelectVoice("Eliska22k");// here program just exit without any exeption
voice.Rate = 2;

voice.SpeakAsync("Ahoj, jak se máš?");
```

SAPI5

```
SpVoice voice = new SpVoice();

voice.Voice = voice.GetVoices().Item(6);// index of eliska voice
voice.Rate = 2;

voice.Speak("Ahoj, jak se máš?", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync);//here occurs exeption
```

Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: +1 for Ahoj, jak se máš?

Comment: seeing the same problem with the standard text to speech packs

Comment: added easy repro to this thread on msdn http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b575f661-aa78-4db4-b145-b328ecfbde63/problems-pausing-and-restarting-texttospeech?forum=winappswithcsharp

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can tell this software is not yet compatible with Windows 8.

Xtranormal developed these voice packs to go with their text to animation software as an add on.

Checking out the reviews of this software from [PC World](http://www.pcworld.com/product/952356/xtranormal-state.html) suggests the specs of their 2.5 beta was for Windows XP and Windows Vista.

Note that PCWorld review was made in 2010. Windows 7 support was integrated after this review.

Noting the lag behind Windows 7 release and the upgrade of this software to Windows 7 compatibility also strengthens my argument that this is not yet windows 8 ready.
(5 months after windows 7 was released pc world reviewed this software, which was not windows 7 compatible, windows 8 has not yet been out that long, upgrading software takes time ;) )

Checking out their technical details on [their own website](http://www.xtranormal.com/about-desktop) suggests a recommended setup of using Windows 7 at the latest.

This to me suggests they have not yet updated it to Windows 8.

(As an additional FootNote, not a single tutorial on YouTube of this software with windows 8, but plenty with the other OS's, people make a tutorial about anything these days and the lack of one for this OS (despite the applications increasing popularity over the period of 2 years suggests once more, no Windows 8 yet ;)

A note on the footnote, Software Informer is a site where nearly every piece of software available is reviewed, older versions have recieved 2 - 3 reviews compared to the 260 submitted for the most recent version, hence the known popularity increase
)

Footnote 2; the reason i focused on the software was because the voices are designed for that software initially. Therefore if the voices were to receive an upgrade, the software they intended it to be used for first is likely to be upgraded first)

You think they would just say on their site somewhere what OS's they support :/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer, but I have run into the same exact error whenever I was trying to reuse the same media element to play a different stream over and over (user is button mashing, for example). The solution was to use an explicit GC.Collect(). Though having 5 media elements is kinda nice also as it seems to speed things up with stopping and restarting audio.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Media.SpeechSynthesis;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace SpeechMark
{
  /// <summary>
  /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
  /// </summary>
  public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
  {
    public BlankPage1()
    {
      this.InitializeComponent();

      m_button.Click += m_button_Click;

      m_audioPlayerPool = new MediaElement[5];
      for(int index = 0; index < m_audioPlayerPool.Length; index++)
      {
        var audioPlayer = new MediaElement();
        audioPlayer.AutoPlay = true;
        m_audioPlayerPool[index] = audioPlayer;
        m_grid.Children.Add(audioPlayer);
      }

      m_textToSpeech = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    }

    async void m_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      m_button.IsEnabled = false;
      if (m_audioPlayer != null)
      {
        m_audioPlayer.Stop();
      }

      if (m_stream != null)
      {
        m_stream.Dispose();
        m_stream = null;
      }

      GC.Collect();

      m_audioPlayer = m_audioPlayerPool[m_nextAudioPlayerToUse];
      m_nextAudioPlayerToUse = (m_nextAudioPlayerToUse + 1) % m_audioPlayerPool.Length;

      string ssml = "<speak version=\"1.0\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis\" xml:lang=\"en\"><voice gender=\"female\" xml:lang=\"en\"><prosody rate=\"1\">how are you doing</prosody><mark name=\"utteranceComplete\"/></voice></speak>";
      m_stream = await m_textToSpeech.SynthesizeSsmlToStreamAsync(ssml);
      m_audioPlayer.SetSource(m_stream, m_stream.ContentType);

      m_button.IsEnabled = true;
    }

    private MediaElement m_audioPlayer;
    private MediaElement[] m_audioPlayerPool;
    private int m_nextAudioPlayerToUse = 0;
    private SpeechSynthesizer m_textToSpeech;
    public SpeechSynthesisStream m_stream { get; set; }
  }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="SpeechMark.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SpeechMark"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="m_grid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Button x:Name="m_button" Height="128" Margin="446,303,0,337" Width="256"/>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```